# "typings install" not generating the browser.d.ts file

Tags: typescript

I am using typescript for my development. I installed typings globally using node. And here is my typings.json file.

```
{
  "name": "nightride-queuing-simulator",
  "version": false,
  "globalDependencies": {
    "google.maps": "registry:dt/google.maps#3.20.0+20160414124451"
  }
}
```

The problem is that 
1. I am unable to generate the browser.t.ds file while running the "typings install" command..

2. I do not understand why I have to give globalDependency. It ran in windows machine without mentioning "global". Now I am running in Ubuntu machine and it started throwing the following error
   (Not sure whether it is OS dependent but just mentioning it).
   [Attempted to compile "google.maps" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/505)

Please help me with this.

Comment: Your question was answered in your issue. You have two different versions of typings between ubuntu and windows.

Comment: Okay is it because of that? I will try the same in mac and get back....

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are using the new major release of typings (1.0) on your Ubuntu machine and an old version (< 1.0) on your Windows machine. This new version no longer creates a *browser.d.ts* file (Read [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/151) and see the new version information [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0))

Make sure both machines are using the same version. I would recommend updating both to typings 1.0:

```
npm i -g typings
# in your project root:
rm -rf typings
# update your typings.json file to comply with the new 1.0 version, then run:
typings install
```

Comment: But I am using the referencing browser.d.ts in my typescript file..... So should I replace it and refer it to index.d.ts file?

Comment: @BaradwajAryasomayajula yes: "removed browser.d.ts by default, should use typings/index.d.ts by default" - [Release information](https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0)